# Airflow task not retrying properly upon failure

Tags: python, airflow

I created an Airflow task with a retry count and it doesn't seem to actually retry when running my airflow test.

```
def verify_pod_initialization(deployments):
   raise ValueError("test")
```

```
verify_deployments = PythonOperator(
    task_id='verify_pod_initialization', 
    retries=5, 
    python_callable=verify_pod_initialization, 
    op_kwargs={'deployments': {'etl-pipeline': 3}},
    dag=dag
```

I'm testing via: `airflow test hello_world verify_pod_initialization 2015-06-01`.

Everything runs fine, but I'm hoping to prove to myself that running the test, I can see it run X times -> fail, then later, pass. Currently, it runs once. Just wondering best practices and also how I can get it to actually retry if it fails. Is `ValueError` not what I want?

I've ripped out the business logic from my task to ease my explanation.

Comment: I don't think using the `airflow test` command will go through the retry flow if that's what you're expecting. I would try just turning the DAG on in the UI and letting it run like normal.

Comment: I tried triggering the DAG from UI and it ran 6 times. First run and 5retries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that this is exactly how you define retries. When you get Airflow up and running with its **scheduler** component, this will work exactly as you expect.

---

Airflow essentially builds models that define how to execute compute tasks, but in production it uses the **scheduler** to add and evaluate data to make sure those compute tasks are run at the right time. As a consequence, some of the models and features work specifically for pieces inside its own architecture.

First, Airflow has its CLI which will allow you to use a command to run a specified compute task. This is the result of your command. It essentially finds the right compute task, generates a task instance with the date value you pass to it and executes it.

However, on top of the CLI, Airflow has a system component called a **scheduler**. The **scheduler** uses the underlying data models to essentially calculate and determine which compute task has met its dependencies and requires a run.

In that context, the **scheduler** repeatedly scans your DAGs to see if there are Tasks that  have  all of their dependencies met. If they have, it generates a Task Instance with `retries=0`. An **executor** performs the compute. The **executor** takes the information from trying to execute the task and updates the model or backend database. If it failed it also gives the status field a `failed` status. The next time the **scheduler** reads the database it will see a failed task, it will then compare the retries value against the configured retries. If it deduces that it is allow to retry again `retries < max_retries-1` and the state is failed, it will change its state, add 1 to retries, and pass the instruction to the **executor**.

Alternatively, if `retries == max_retries - 1` the scheduler will set the status of the Task to failed, notify that the task has failed, and not retry the task.